# Python BS4 can not extract data properly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have this source code

```
<div class="field-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="label-fluid">Email Address</div>
    <div class="data-fluid rev-field" aria-data="rei-0">maldapalmer<span class="hd-form-field">ajk89;fjioasjdfwjepu90f30 v09u30r nv8704rhnv987rjl3409u0asu[amav084-8235 087307304u0[9fd0]] asf74 john 9@#83r8cva sarah sj4t8g@!$%#7h v7hgv 398#$&amp;&amp;^@7y9</span>@gmail<span class="hd-form-field">ajk89;fjioasjdfwjepu90f30 v09u30r nv8704rhnv987rjl3409u0asu[amav084-8235 087307304u0[9fd0]] asf74 john 9@#83r8cva sarah sj4t8g@!$%#7h v7hgv 398#$&amp;&amp;^@7y9</span>.com</div>
</div>
```

I seem to be doing everything right however I just can not extract the email address housed in the second div within the main div element. This is my code:

```
fields = []
for row in rows:
    fields.append(row.find_all('div', recursive = False))
email = fields[0][0].find(class_ = "data-fluid rev-field").text
```

Row here is the element within the main div is housed. Any suggestions are welcome, also I hope I explained the issue well enough.

The problem I get is that the string shows up empty ''. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract Email by using the following code:

```
from bs4 import *
from requests import get
response = get('http://127.0.0.1/bs.html') # Replce 'http://127.0.0.1/bs.html' with your URL
sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
email = sp.find('div', class_= "data-fluid rev-field").text
spn = sp.find('span', class_= "hd-form-field").text
email = email.replace(spn,"")
print(email)
```

Output:

```
maldapalmer@gmail.com
```